# Tournament Schedule Assignment via Convex Optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

I am tasked with setting up a schedule for a sports "potluck" tournament as follows.

Everyone signs up as individuals, and are sorted into "pods" of 4-5 people where each pod has roughly the same average skill level to keep the games interesting. Teams of 8-10 players are made by combining 2 pods together and facing them off against an opposing team of 2 other pods. In this way, each pod (ideally) plays with every other pod once and against every other pod twice over the course of the day. One team plays in black jerseys and the other team white. A target setup would have N=9 pods so that each pod plays in 8 out of 18 games on a single field of play (each pod sits out for 10/18 time slots).

The ideal schedule would have the following attributes:

1. Each pod plays with every other pod exactly once
2. Each pod plays against every other pod exactly twice
3. No pod that plays consecutive games much switch colors (to give time to switch jerseys)
4. Of the remaining valid solutions, minimize the total number of color switches across all pods

Is it possible to formulate either this problem or its relaxation as a convex optimization? Is there some way to either obtain one such valid schedule (for N=9, say), or prove that no such schedule exists that satisfies #1-#3?

I thought I would be able to come up with a schedule manually, but it is trickier than anticipated. [Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBRR1.png) I manually constructed that obeys constraints #1 and #3 but not #2.

It seems like something like the [Hungarian Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) could work in this case, with vector elements of +-1 to denote black/white, and zero to denote sitting out that game.

Here are some initial thoughts along those lines. Denote X[i,j] as +-1 when pod j plays black/white in game i, and 0 if it sits this game out. The following convex constraints seem to handle the basic rules and #3:

- (C1) $-1 \leq X[i,j] \leq +1$
- (C2) $\sum_j X[i,j] = 0$
- (C3) $\sum_j |X[i,j]| = 4$
- (C4) $| {\rm diff}_i\{X\}[i,j]| <= 1$

The following constraints, or something like them could work for #1 and #2:

- (C5) $\langle X[:,j_1],X[:,j_2] \rangle  = -1 ~~~ \forall j_1, j_2$
- (C6) $\langle |X[:,j_1]| , |X[:,j_2]| \rangle = 3 ~~~ \forall j_1, j_2$

Although it gets dicey with these cross-terms and abs, so I suppose it's no longer a linear program, and is now something else?

For #4, it seems nontrivial to set up under this formulation. The naive approach would minimize sum_{i,j} (abs(diff_i(X[i,j]))), but this would be incorrect because a pod schedule of +1, 0, +1, 0, +1,  involves no change in jersey color. So it might be necessary to give up on #4 and just focus on a valid solution satisfying #1-#3.

Comment: This can be modeled as either an integer linear program or a constraint programming problem, but I don't think your choice of variables $X$ will get you very far, particularly with the partner once/oppose twice part. Also, are you assuming that this can be done in 9 rounds of games (9 time slots)? I'm not sure that is feasible.

Comment: N=9 pods, 18 games. See the example linked. 

The partner once-oppose twice is relatively easy, see the last two inner product constraints. It's #4 that's the tough one under this formulation.

Could you propose an alternative formulation with either ILP or CPP?

Comment: The linked example suggests something missing from the problem statement: that only one game is being played at a time. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. I added some text to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer linear program with binary variables will do the job. There is more than one way to model it. I have an IP model that seems to work, in the sense that it produces feasible solutions, but the bound is rather loose, so proof of optimality could take quite a while.

The model might be too cumbersome to display here in its full glory, but I can least list the variables and describe the constraints. First, some terminology: a "team" is a pair of pods playing together, and each game is divided into two "slots" (white and black, as in jersey colors). There are 36 possible teams, each of which needs to play exactly once, and 36 slots. The variables used in my model (all binary) are:

- $x_{t,s}=1$ if team $t$ plays in slot $s$, 0 if not;
- $y_{p,\hat{p},s}=1$ if pod $p$ is playing in slot $s$ and is opposed by a team containing pod $\hat{p}\neq p$;
- $z_{p,g}=0$ if pod $p$ is wearing color 0 (white) during game $g$ and 1 if it is wearing color 1 (black) during game $g$ (regardless of whether pod $p$ is actually playing in game $g$ or not); and
- $w_{p,g}=1$ if pod $p$ changes its jersey color going into game $g$.

The objective is to minimize the sum of the $w$ variables. There are sets of constraints as follows:

- every team is assigned to exactly one slot;
- every slot is filled exactly once;
- the $y$ variables are defined by inequalities involving the $x$ variables;
- every pair of pods are opponents exactly twice;
- the slot a team plays in determines the jerseys worn during that game by the pods in the team (which has the side effect of preventing a pod from playing against itself);
- no pod plays in consecutive games in different colors; and
- the color jersey worn by a pod during a game is the same as the color worn in the previous game (regardless of whether the pod plays in either game) unless a change occurs and is counted.

Addendum: By request, here is the best solution I found (14 jersey changes, running the IP model with a time limit of 30 minutes).

```
Game  1: 1 & 3 vs. 7 & 8
Game  2: 3 & 9 vs. 2 & 4
Game  3: 1 & 9 vs. 2 & 8
Game  4: 5 & 9 vs. 3 & 7
Game  5: 5 & 8 vs. 2 & 6
Game  6: 1 & 5 vs. 6 & 9
Game  7: 1 & 2 vs. 6 & 7
Game  8: 2 & 9 vs. 3 & 6
Game  9: 8 & 9 vs. 4 & 5
Game 10: 3 & 8 vs. 4 & 6
Game 11: 2 & 3 vs. 5 & 7
Game 12: 3 & 4 vs. 1 & 6
Game 13: 4 & 9 vs. 1 & 7
Game 14: 4 & 8 vs. 2 & 7
Game 15: 1 & 4 vs. 2 & 5
Game 16: 1 & 8 vs. 3 & 5
Game 17: 4 & 7 vs. 5 & 6
Game 18: 7 & 9 vs. 6 & 8
```

Addendum 2: Responding to the issue of pods playing in four consecutive games, here is a (not necessarily optimal) schedule with 16 jersey changes and some streaks of three consecutive games, but no streaks of four consecutive games.

```
Game  1: 3 & 7 vs. 4 & 8
Game  2: 5 & 7 vs. 1 & 9
Game  3: 4 & 5 vs. 6 & 9
Game  4: 3 & 4 vs. 1 & 2
Game  5: 3 & 6 vs. 1 & 8
Game  6: 4 & 7 vs. 2 & 5
Game  7: 3 & 8 vs. 5 & 9
Game  8: 2 & 6 vs. 1 & 7
Game  9: 4 & 6 vs. 7 & 8
Game 10: 1 & 4 vs. 5 & 8
Game 11: 2 & 3 vs. 5 & 6
Game 12: 4 & 9 vs. 1 & 6
Game 13: 2 & 9 vs. 6 & 8
Game 14: 7 & 9 vs. 1 & 3
Game 15: 6 & 7 vs. 3 & 5
Game 16: 2 & 7 vs. 8 & 9
Game 17: 2 & 4 vs. 3 & 9
Game 18: 2 & 8 vs. 1 & 5
```

Comment: I appreciate the fresh perspective, and this proposed formulation does appear to have sufficient descriptive power to hit all constraints and the objective function. Do you have some source that connects this to a solver (after relaxing to standard LP presumably)?

Comment: The problem is inherently discrete, so it's an IP rather than an LP. I've got three blog posts (third coming out tomorrow) giving an overview (first post) and describing both an integer programming model (second post) and a constraint programming (CP) model (third post). Somewhat to my surprise, the IP model does better finding feasible solutions than the CP model does. The first post is at https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2022/02/tournament-scheduling-cplex-v-cp.html. It links to Java source code (using CPLEX and CP Optimizer solvers).

Comment: Thanks. The blog posts are nicely described. I hadn't realized there were efficient ways of solving IPs. Because they are NP-hard, I had thought relaxing was required for computational reasons, so it's good to know there are fast approximations out there.

I'm having trouble getting the code to run due to missing dependencies. (Also, I'm not well versed in Java, so I had to enlist the help of my brother, but he had a hard time getting it to run too.) Could you post the output solution at pastebin.com or similar?

Comment: I don't have an optimal solution. I'll add a solution with 14 jersey changes as an edit to my answer. If you have access to an IP solver that reads LP format model files, I can dump the model to a file and you can try running that for as long as you like.

Comment: Even a feasible solution was more than I was able to come up with on my own. #4 was always the icing on the cake. Thanks! I realize I should have either constrained the number of consecutive games per pod to prevent "exhaustion". 3-game runs are tolerable but not ideal, but 4-game runs should be eliminated entirely to the extent possible.

Comment: It should be straightforward to include this in the formulation you propose. Perhaps each 3-game run should have an associated penalty of "C" jersey switches (maybe C~=5), and 4-game runs should be prevented entirely as a hard constraint (2-game runs are necessary and therefore tolerable). Another variation is to try to minimize the maximum "cost" per pod, to prevent any one pod from being significantly disadvantaged relative to the others, even if that means increasing the average cost.

Comment: I was able to make some trivial changes (permute game order) to the schedule you provided to cut in half the 2x 4-runs and 4x 3-runs (1x and 2x, respectively), but this is as far as I was able to get. (See result [here](https://i.imgur.com/uRAKhRC.png).) It looks like there's a python wrapper. I'd like to try to reproduce these results on my own "someday".

Comment: Adding a hard constraint to avoid runs of four games is straightforward. Penalizing runs of three straights games is straightforward to code, but requires a decision how many additional jersey changes is a fair "price" for avoiding a three game run.

Comment: I added to my answer a schedule with 16 jersey changes and 3-runs but no 4-runs. Other criteria you might consider include escalating penalties for 3-runs by each pod (meaning a pod's second 3-run is hit with a larger penalty than their first 3-run, etc.), to distribute 3-runs evenly ... at a possible cost of more jersey changes.

Comment: Makes sense. The "C" variable mentioned above was the one I proposed for this tradeoff ratio between jersey changes and 3-runs (1 3-run is as painful as C jersey changes, with C=5 proposed). Is your solver able to come up with any solutions that prohibit 3-runs as well as 4-runs as a hard constraint, or is this too prohibitive? (I'd imagine that would drive jersey changes up into the 20s or 30s, if any feasible solution existed.)

Comment: I did a half-hour run with a hard limit of two consecutive games for any pod. It produced an incumbent (not necessarily optimal) with 17 jersey changes.

Comment: Better than expected, only having to sacrifice one jersey change to eliminate all 3-runs. Good to know.

Comment: Bear in mind that neither the 16 changes with 3-runs nor the 17 changes with 2-runs is known to be optimal, so the sacrifice in optimal solutions could be more than one (or could be zero).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind linear program. It's not even convex, due to the L1-equality-constraint (C3). Nor will relaxing help: the corresponding convexified inequality constraint $\sum_j |X[i,j]| \leq 4$  will be insufficient to prevent the trivial solution $X=0$.

It seems necessary to model the "envelope" explicitly so that $X[i,j] = P[i,j] C[i,j]$ for binary function $P[i,j]$, that is one if pod $j$ plays game $i$ and zero otherwise. Sign-valued jersey color $C[i,j]$ is $\pm 1$ to denote jersey colors during a game, and is allowed to ``float'' to intermediate values during games that the pod sits out, allowing better modeling of the objective function #4.

Then we have:

(DO) $\min \sum_{i,j} |C[i,j]-C[i-1,j]|$

subject to:

- (D1) $-1 \leq C[i,j] \leq 1 ~~~ \forall i,j$
- (D2) $0 \leq P[i,j] \leq 1 ~~~ \forall i,j$
- (D3) $|C[i,j] - C[i-1,j]| \leq 1 ~~~ \forall i,j$
- (D4) $\sum_i P[i,j] = N-1 ~~~ \forall j$
- (D5) $\sum_j P[i,j] = 4 ~~~ \forall i$
- (D6) $\sum_j C[i,j] P[i,j] = 0 ~~~ \forall i$
- (D7) $\sum_i P[i,j_1] P[i,j_2] = 3 ~~~ \forall j_1, j_2$
- (D8) $\sum_i C[i,j_1] P[i,j_1] C[i,j_2] P[i,j_2] = -1 ~~~ \forall j_1, j_2$

Well... this isn't exactly convex either, but at least is more amenable to convexification. The following approximation to the above seems closer to the mark...

(EO)  $ \min   \sum_{i,j} |C[i,j]-C[i-1,j]| $

subject to:

- (E1) $~ -1 \leq C[i,j] \leq 1 ~~~ \forall i,j $
- (E2) $~ 0 \leq P[i,j] \leq 1 ~~~ \forall i,j $
- (E3) $ |C[i,j] - C[i-1,j]| \leq 1 ~~~ \forall i,j $
- (E4) $ \sum_i P[i,j] = N-1 ~~~ \forall j $
- (E5) $ \sum_j P[i,j] = 4 ~~~ \forall i $
- (E6) $ | \sum_j C[i,j] P[i,j]| \leq 0 ~~~ \forall i $
- (E7) $ \sum_i P[i,j_1] P[i,j_2] \leq 3 ~~~ \forall j_1, j_2 $
- (E8) $\sum_i C[i,j_1] C[i,j_2] = -1 ~~~ \forall j_1, j_2$